Reading another process heap memory from a kernel module
I have a kernel module and I am trying to read a user land process. I have been searching for a way to do it in the kernel and have not had any luck.
I made a user land program that would parse the /proc/pid/maps to get a range of addresses on a process. Then from there I could call process_vm_readv() on the addresses and it worked. However I am not able to get this to work in kernel. Does the kernel have any other methods for reading process memory?

How do you know your userland program worked? Isn't it possible you read your own program's virtual memory at the address you found in maps?

@wxz I used a PID to a different process.

I looked up that function you used. It says it bypasses kernel space. But since you're copying data from one buffer to another, does this question help?
